# Embedding MVC Model variables int Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have some Javascript code shown below. It uses a replacement variables from the model which are working fine - however I cannot work out how to get the content location from the model. I have

```
 function drawChart() {
    $.post('@Url.Content("~/Home/GetDataAssets")', function (d) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);
        var options = {
            title: '@Model.Title',
            width: '@Model.Width',
            height: '@Model.Title',
            allowHtml: @Model.AllowHtml,
            is3D: @Model.Is3D
            };
```

But I want the  @Url.Content line to look something like

```
    $.post('@Url.Content("@Model.ContentLocation")', function (d) {
```

Which doesn't work as it thinks that @Model.ContentLocation is a string. When I try escaping the quotes I do not get the required result as they are being Html encoded. I believe that is because I am doing it incorrectly.

What is the correct way to encode the quotes so that the data will be read from the location in the model variable?

With the help of Stephen Muecke I have got this working. The line making the post should have been:

```
$.post('@Url.Content(Model.ContentLocation )', function (d)
```

Comment: What does `var url = '@Model.ContentLocation';` return?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this...I do not know how apply that ti what I have. If I add this code then the variable url would be inside the double quotes and they would still need escaping?

Comment: if `var url = '@Model.ContentLocation';` returns a valid url (e.g. `/Home/GetDataAssets`, then it can be just `$.post(url, function() {...`

Comment: I just get nothing displayed. changing the line
   `$.post("@Url.Content("~/Home/GetDataAssets")", function (d) { `
to
   `$.post("~/Home/GetDataAssets", function (d) {`
also gives nothing, so I assume that `@Url.Content` is needed

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"get nothing displayed"_. Do you mean its not calling the controller method. What errors do you see in the browser console. And you still have not said what `var url = '@Model.ContentLocation';` returns

Comment: Sorry `var url = '@Model.ContentLocation';` returns ~/Home/GetDataAssets

Comment: When I say nothing is displayed I mean that the graph does not appear...Which is what happens if the call to get the data to populate it does not exist (among other things)

Comment: Open you browser tools and inspect the console. What errors are displayed?

Comment: Create javascript variables and assign the razor values to those first. Then pass in the variables to your script.

Comment: Thanks for you help Stephen. I have got this working now. The Post line should have been:
`$.post('@Url.Content(Model.ContentLocation )', function (d)`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not understand MVC `"~/..."` path syntax.  If your intention is to use that in Ajax `post` or `get` you need to get the actual path of that virtual path.  To do that, you can do this from the server side code when you setup the model:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext); 
var model = new ModelClassNameHere {
    ContentLocation = urlHelper.Content("~/blah/nicepic.jpg") };

return View(model);
```

One other thing that I'd suggest is to cache all these server side model properties into a global page setting in JavaScript as to centralized things and not having @Model.blah everywhere.  Beside if you are going to split your javascript files into multiple files during development, this is just good practice.

See this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZlOL0n

I am using `angular.module.value` to cache that global `pageSettings` that contains server side model contents so I can pass them around in angular.  See how the `settings` value are injected into the controller.